# Select a JTable row

Tags: java, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I was trying to select my row from JTable by click, from GUI. I select it well, but when I'm trying to delete something I get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2>=1

```
    if(row >=  0) 
    {
    String id = table_1.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString(); // here I got the error
    int idd = Integer.parseInt(id);
    Account account = bank.getAccounts().get(idd);
    bank.removeAccount(account);
    }
```

How can I solve it??

Comment: What is determining the value of the variable **row**? It should be something like: `row = table_1.getSelectedRow();`.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in try and catch and make sure that the variable Row get the desired value. I was facing a similar issue and all I had to do was work on the data on a different thread as compared to the AWT thread that should only work on GUI elements. and never update a GUI element from any thread but the AWT thread. if you are getting these values from a database then delete from database using a different thread and then use the AWT thread to repaint your GUI accordingly.

An easy way to figure this out is if when you try to do the delete multiple times the IndexOutOfBounds exception changes its value, for eg if once it is 2>=1 and the second time it is 3>=2 or something else, if it keeps changing you need to handle threads better.  Hope this helps.